# What does the op column mean in pyflink when print table result

Tags: pyflink

When I do a join query using pyflink sql and print the result, there are some duplicate rows where a op column is displayed as in attached screenshot, any idea what that is and how can I produce non-duplicate result? Thanks in advance.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A4I1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You've apparently done a streaming join (rather than a batch join), where the result is an updating (or changelog) stream. +I is an insert, -U is a retraction, and +U is an update. +D would be a deletion.

With a streaming join, Flink SQL will continuously update the result as new inputs are processed. What you are seeing is how this is represented by the PrintSink. If you run this same query in batch execution mode, then only the final result will be printed out. That's one way to get what you want. Another option would be to use a sink that can handle streaming upserts, such as the JDBC sink.